# how to delete an item from shopping cart by button click in android

Tags: android, button, shopping-cart

I can delete an item from shopping list through long press on the selected item by the following code

```
  listcart.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


               model=d.get(i);
               final String orderno=model.getOrderno();
               AlertDialog.Builder msg=new AlertDialog.Builder(CartActivity.this)
                       .setTitle("Delete Item")
                       .setMessage("Are you sure delete this item "+model.getItemname())
                       .setIcon(R.drawable.applogo)
                       .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface,int i){
                               DBLite db=new DBLite(CartActivity.this);
                               db.DeleteItem(orderno);
                               d=new ArrayList<>(db.GetCart(CartActivity.this));
                               adapterCart=new Cart_Adapter(CartActivity.this,d);
                               listcart.setAdapter(adapterCart);
                               txtOrderTotal.setText(String.valueOf(db.GetSum()));

                           }
                       }).setNegativeButton("No",null);
               msg.create();
               msg.show();
               return false;
           }
    });
```

I want to delete this item by clicking (x) image. How can I customize that code for that purpose, like the image below:

[image: screenshot from app]

Comment: Where is that button placed is it inside the list or outside of the list?

Comment: Can you explain more about your problem?
like where is your button, wh

Comment: the button is inside the item_Layout which is loaded in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a way and it works. i deal with delete button through cartAdapter activity in which c=context , ass=arrayList<>

```
   viewHolder.imgdelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AlertDialog.Builder msg=new AlertDialog.Builder(c)
                    .setTitle("Delete Item")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure delete this item "+data.getItemname())
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.applogo)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface,int i){
                            DBLite db=new DBLite(c);
                            db.DeleteItem(data.getOrderno());
                            ass=new ArrayList<>(db.GetCart(c));
                            adapterCart=new Cart_Adapter(c,ass);
                            listcart.setAdapter((ListAdapter) adapterCart);
                            txtOrderTotal.setText(String.valueOf(db.GetSum()));

                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton("No",null);
            msg.create();
            msg.show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a button inside your item layout. Take its reference in your Cart_Adapter adapter class and do this inside `getView()` method of your adapter (if it is BaseAdapter or ArrayAdapter). But if it is recyclerview adapter then write this inside `onBindView()` method of that:

```
    viewholder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // write code here to delete item and refresh adapter
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to setup your adapter again, if it's already loaded. Try this code into your dialog positive button of your `AlertDialog()` which will be called from your `onBindViewHolder()` method in your adapter class.

```
 <yourViewHolderObject>.deleteIcon.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener() { 
  // like: deleteIcon = view.findViewById(R.id.deleteIcon);
       @Override
       public boolean onClick(View view, int i) {

           model=d.get(i);
           final String orderno=model.getOrderno();
           AlertDialog.Builder msg=new AlertDialog.Builder(CartActivity.this)
                   .setTitle("Delete Item")
                   .setMessage("Are you sure delete this item "+model.getItemname())
                   .setIcon(R.drawable.applogo)
                   .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface,int i){
                           DBLite db=new DBLite(CartActivity.this);
                           db.DeleteItem(orderno);
                           // Also delete this item from your current list
                           listcart.remove(model);
                           d=new ArrayList<>(db.GetCart(CartActivity.this));
                           adapterCart=new Cart_Adapter(CartActivity.this,d);
                           //listcart.setAdapter(adapterCart); // exclude this
                           adapterCart.notifyDataSetChanged(); // include this
                           // this line your reload and update your list
                           txtOrderTotal.setText(String.valueOf(db.GetSum()));

                       }
                   }).setNegativeButton("No",null);
           msg.create();
           msg.show();
           return false;
       }
});
```